# How to change the text color of div which is looped by ngFor?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have a div which is looped using ngFor, now whenever I click one of the divs in the loop I want to change the text color of that particular div, and then after that if I click any other div in the loop, then that div only will have his color changed and the previous clicked div will have its text color changed to the initial value. [Using Angular 2 only].

For example:

```
<div *ngFor="let x of y; let i= index" (click)="changeColor()"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A working solution to your problem is as follows:

Change the template code to following:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'selected-color' : i==selectedIndex}"
     *ngFor="let x of y; let i= index" (click)="changeColor(i)">

     <!-- print anything here -->

</div>
```

Notice here that I added `[ngClass]` and binded it with a condition. Also notice that the index is passed into `changeColor(i)`

Now in your component class:

```
public selectedIndex;

changeColor(i){
    this.selectedIndex = i;
  }
```

Define the css class for the background color, as you wish:

```
.selected-color{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Everything should be working fine now.